# Indeed.com API frustrations. Anyone know where I can find an independent feed?

Tags: javascript, xml, api

I am currently in the process of creating an app that integrates the Google Maps API with the Indeed.com API.  However, after several unsuccessful attempts at finding the API, I'm at a standstill.  Does anyone know where to find the XML file or feed that I can link the app to?  Or a database of some sort?  I know how it works if you want to redirect to Indeed.com, but I want to do this independently of their site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first stop is always Programmable Web: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/indeed

Hopefully the documentation you need is linked to from there.  If not, well I guess they really don't want you using their API, do they? :)

Comment: THANKS! I got it!  Apparently, I have to predict the namespaces they use.  Thank goodness order doesn't matter.  Thank you so much!

Comment: hei @Thorne do you mind to mark answer above by Andrew as resolution?